# Error establishing in database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which works perfectly. But some times when I refresh the page several times using <kbd>F5</kbd> key, then my site goes down for several minutes or for about half an hour and shows message

> "Error establishing in database connection".

My database user name , password , host etc all are right. And my site works perfectly. But it shows this error only some times. If database connection are not perfect then it must show this message all the time. I have also written custom database connection in seperate files.

Comment: Check your error log file, you may get more information about this issue

Comment: My suggestion is this issues may be caused by loop open files limit in MySQL

Comment: @kannan Now  i am trying to login in my php myadmin which is giving error " #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

Comment: Is wordpress error is due to phpmyadmin error

Comment: Try through terminal

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have fixed a few English issues.  I have also tagged F5 with kbd and marked down your error with >  

I think  you need to provide some details on your page, in case there is an issue with your code.

Comment: Your error is being caused **most probably** because your system does not have a connection pool to manage the connections, so everytime you hit F5 several times you are opening new connections to the database which is being accounted for on the max_connection limit configuration of the mysql database (read it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html). In order to solve your problem you will have to search on that for your wordpress system. Since I'm not familiarized with it, can't help more than this. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time this error message is caused by a problem in the wp-config file.

Add this code in **wp-config.php**

`define(‘WP_ALLOW_REPAIR’, true);`

yourdomain.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

Click repair and optimize button to repair your database.

> Make sure you remove this line of code after you have fixed your database connection error message.

If you still have this issues, contact your hosting provider. They will fix this easily.